# Casting to an unsigned int, then casting back, C

Tags: c, stack, int, unsigned

If I have a stack S, filled with signed ints, I want to do the following:
POP two values and cast it to an unsigned int, then add them together, and then push back a SIGNED sum.
I did the following, but I don't know if it's correct:

```
unsigned int x = (unsigned int)pop(S)
unsigned int y = (unsigned int)pop(S)
int sum = x+y
push(S, sum);
pc++
```

Am I on the right track?
Also, can someone explain to me a little bit about explicit casting?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to cast at all?

Comment: what type does `pop(S)` return?

Comment: pop returns an 32bit int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in the sense that your code does precisely what you say it should do. The real question is whether or not that is what you are looking to achieve.

A negative number cast to unsigned int becomes a very large positive number. For example, negative one becomes the largest positive integer that can be expressed in an unsigned int after the cast to unsigned (try it!) When you add two negative numbers that were cast to unsigned, you are guaranteed to get an overflow. If that is indeed what you are trying to do, your code is definitely doing it.

Comment: Ya, I'm trying do that. But Whenever I printf("%d\n", x) for example, it still gives me a signed integer, which is why I don't know if what I'm doing is working.

Comment: @de1337ed This is because you need to tell printf to not to cast your unsigned back to signed: `printf("%u\n", x)`.

Comment: Even if you don't do the addition, you will get overflow.  The following invokes implementation-defined behaviour: `(int)(unsigned int)-1`.

Comment: You can't trust what printf tells you because it's stupid about matching the type in the format string with the type in the passed in argument.  You could pass in a float and try to print it with %d, and printf would happily try.  Try printing with "%u\n".

Comment: That makes sense. Another quick question, do I need to do unsigned int x = (unsigned int)pop(S) or does unsigned int x = pop(S) suffice?

Comment: @de1337ed I think you'll see a warning about signed/unsigned conversion if you omit the cast, but the code will compile and run the same.